# How to create a function which returns all the leap and non leap years in given range in Python?

Tags: python, logic

I want to create a function which takes 2 different dates as input from user in a single input field like dd/mm/yyyy format and gives us all the leap years between that range of date in one list and non-leap years in different list.
It would be good if it's in Python3

I have although created function but don't know how to take that input in a single line and then extract year from it.

```
#Leap Year Program

year = int(input("Enter the Starting Year: "))

year2 = int(input("Enter the Ending Year: "))

s = []

b = []

for i in range(year,(year2)+1):
    if i % 4 == 0:
        if i % 100 != 0:
            s.append(i) 
        elif i % 100 == 0:
           if i % 400 == 0:
                s.append(i)
           else:
                b.append(i)
    else:
        b.append(i)

print("Leap Years: ",end="") 
   

for x in range(len(s)):
              
    print(s[x],end=", ")

print("\n")

# printing non leap year

print(" Non Leap Years: ",end="")        
for x in range(len(b)):                   #Converting List of Non- 
Leap-Years into form of output by traversing it
print(b[x],end=", ")
```

Comment: Show your code properly formatted in the question.

Comment: @Shikhar Please [edit] your post to include the functino that your created. Please paste the text of the function and not a picture/screenshot of the text

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to see your single input field to know how to split the string how we need. But here's an example function that accepts 2 parameters, start and end date. It will return you two separate lists, one with all the leap years, and one with non-leap years.

```
def get_leap_years(start_date, end_date):
    # Extract the year from the start and end dates
    start_year = int(start_date.split("/")[-1])
    end_year = int(end_date.split("/")[-1])
    
    # Initialize lists to store the leap years and non-leap years
    leap_years = []
    non_leap_years = []
    
    # Iterate through each year in the range specified by the start and end dates
    for year in range(start_year, end_year+1):
        # Check if the year is a leap year (divisible by 4, not divisible by 100, or divisible by 400)
        if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0):
            leap_years.append(year)
        else:
            non_leap_years.append(year)

    # Return the lists of leap years and non-leap years
    return leap_years, non_leap_years

# Example of using the function
leap_years, non_leap_years = get_leap_years("01/01/2000", "01/01/2023")

# Example of iterating through result lists.
print('Leap Years:')
for i in leap_years:
    print(i)
print('\nNon-Leap Years:')
for i in non_leap_years:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this

```
import datetime
from typing import Tuple


DATE_FORMAT = "%d/%m/%Y"

def is_leap_year(year: int) -> bool:
    if year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 == 0:
            if year % 400 == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False

def get_leap_and_not_leap_years_list(start: str, end: str) -> Tuple[list, list]:
    # get year from date
    start_year = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, DATE_FORMAT).year
    end_year = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, DATE_FORMAT).year
    
    leap_years, not_leap_years = [], []
    
    for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
        if is_leap_year(year):
            leap_years.append(year)
        else:
            not_leap_years.append(year)
    
    return leap_years, not_leap_years
    
    
leap_years, not_leap_years = get_leap_and_not_leap_years_list("22/03/1995", "4/4/2022")

print(f"{leap_years = }, {not_leap_years = }")
```

Output:

```
leap_years = [1996, 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016, 2020], not_leap_years = [1995, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2021, 2022]
```